# Configuring wercker.yml to run unit tests in a python app requiring postgres service

Tags: python, unit-testing, docker, wercker

I'm trying to use the dockerized version of wercker to run unit tests in a python app but most of my unit tests fail with error `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: No route to host`. The wercker documentation is lacking on the configuration to make this connection.

Perhaps I'm missing something simple but I can't make this db connection to run my tests after spending more time than I should have. Anyway, there are similar questions for Rails apps but the answers are not helping, so perhaps question will help someone else with python app. Looking for SO help!

Below is my current wercker.yml:

```
# http://devcenter.wercker.com/docs/containers/index.html

box: python:3.4.4-onbuild

# You can also use services such as databases. Read more on our dev center:
# http://devcenter.wercker.com/docs/services/index.html

services:
    # http://devcenter.wercker.com/docs/services/postgresql.html
    - id: postgres:9.4
      env:
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mylittlesecret
        POSTGRES_USER: postgres  # optional

# This is the build pipeline. Pipelines are the core of wercker
# Read more about pipelines on our dev center
# http://devcenter.wercker.com/docs/pipelines/index.html

build:
  # The steps that will be executed on build
  # Steps make up the actions in your pipeline
  # Read more about steps on our dev center:
  # http://devcenter.wercker.com/docs/steps/index.html
  steps:
    # A step that sets up the python virtual environment
    - script:
        name: virtualenv install
        code: |
          pip install virtualenv

    - virtualenv:
        name: venv

    - pip-install:
        requirements_file: "requirements.txt"

    # A custom script step, name value is used in the UI
    # and the code value contains the command that get executed
    - script:
        name: echo python information
        code: |
          echo "python version $(python --version) running"
          echo "pip version $(pip --version) running"



    # A step that loads the database schema in order to run the tests - perhaps not needed!!
    - script:
        name: Set up db
        code: |
          echo "Start postgresql server ..."
          echo "Create test db ..."
          echo "Created test db ..."

    # Debug lines I've used in above script
    # export PATH=/usr/pgsql-9.4.6/bin:$PATH  ==> no impact
    # export PATH=/usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin:$PATH  ==> no impact
    # psql -c "CREATE DATABASE scrdbtest;"  ==> ERROR: psql command not found
    # postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/data ==> ERROR: postgres not found

    - script:
        name: run aoscrdb tests
        code: |
          /root/venv/bin/python -m pytest ./tests
```

And here is my apps test config:

```
class TestConfig(Config):
    TESTING = True
    DEBUG = True
    # wercker
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:mylittlesecret@{}:5432/postgres'\
.format(os.environ.get('POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR'))
```

Finally, here one of the is the failing tests from wercker:

```
 ============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.4.4, pytest-2.8.7, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1
rootdir: /pipeline/source/tests, inifile: 
collected 39 items

tests/test_config.py ..
tests/test_forms.py EEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
tests/test_functional.py EEEEEEE
tests/test_models.py EEEEEEEEEEEEEEE

==================================== ERRORS ====================================
___ ERROR at setup of TestRegisterForm.test_validate_user_already_registered ___

app = <Flask 'aoscrdb_app.app'>

    @pytest.yield_fixture(scope='function')
    def db(app):
        """A database for the tests."""
        _db.app = app
        with app.app_context():
>           _db.create_all()

tests/conftest.py:36: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
/root/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:972: in create_all
    self._execute_for_all_tables(app, bind, 'create_all')
/root/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:964: in _execute_for_all_tables
    op(bind=self.get_engine(app, bind), **extra)
/root/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py:3695: in create_all
    tables=tables)
/root/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1855: in _run_visitor
    with self._optional_conn_ctx_manager(connection) as conn:
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/contextlib.py:59: in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
/root/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1848: in _optional_conn_ctx_manager
    with self.contextual_connect() as conn:
/root/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:2039: in contextual_connect
    self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, None),
/root/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:2078: in _wrap_pool_connect
    e, dialect, self)
/root/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1405: in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    exc_info
/root/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py:189: in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=exc_value)
/root/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py:182: in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
/root/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:2074: in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
/root/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py:376: in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
/root/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py:713: in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
/root/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py:480: in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
/root/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py:1060: in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
/root/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py:60: in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
/root/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py:183: in reraise
    raise value
/root/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py:1057: in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
/root/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py:323: in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
/root/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py:449: in __init__
    self.connection = self.__connect()
/root/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py:607: in __connect
    connection = self.__pool._invoke_creator(self)
/root/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py:97: in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
/root/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py:385: in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

dsn = 'dbname=postgres user=postgres password=mysecretpassword host=172.17.0.10'
database = 'postgres', user = 'postgres', password = 'mysecretpassword'
host = '172.17.0.10', port = None, connection_factory = None
cursor_factory = None, async = False, kwargs = {}
items = [('dbname', 'postgres'), ('user', 'postgres'), ('password', 'mysecretpassword'), ('host', '172.17.0.10')]

    def connect(dsn=None,
            database=None, user=None, password=None, host=None, port=None,
            connection_factory=None, cursor_factory=None, async=False, **kwargs):
        """
        Create a new database connection.

        The connection parameters can be specified either as a string:

            conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=postgres password=secret")

        or using a set of keyword arguments:

            conn = psycopg2.connect(database="test", user="postgres", password="secret")

        The basic connection parameters are:

        - *dbname*: the database name (only in dsn string)
        - *database*: the database name (only as keyword argument)
        - *user*: user name used to authenticate
        - *password*: password used to authenticate
        - *host*: database host address (defaults to UNIX socket if not provided)
        - *port*: connection port number (defaults to 5432 if not provided)

        Using the *connection_factory* parameter a different class or connections
        factory can be specified. It should be a callable object taking a dsn
        argument.

        Using the *cursor_factory* parameter, a new default cursor factory will be
        used by cursor().

        Using *async*=True an asynchronous connection will be created.

        Any other keyword parameter will be passed to the underlying client
        library: the list of supported parameters depends on the library version.

        """
        items = []
        if database is not None:
            items.append(('dbname', database))
        if user is not None:
            items.append(('user', user))
        if password is not None:
            items.append(('password', password))
        if host is not None:
            items.append(('host', host))
        if port is not None:
            items.append(('port', port))

        items.extend([(k, v) for (k, v) in kwargs.items() if v is not None])

        if dsn is not None and items:
            raise TypeError(
                "'%s' is an invalid keyword argument when the dsn is specified"
                    % items[0][0])

        if dsn is None:
            if not items:
                raise TypeError('missing dsn and no parameters')
            else:
                dsn = " ".join(["%s=%s" % (k, _param_escape(str(v)))
                    for (k, v) in items])

>       conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
E       sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: No route to host
E           Is the server running on host "172.17.0.10" and accepting
E           TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Comment: Works wonderfully on Travis-CI had it going in 15 minutes.

Comment: You probably need to add a `service-check` step to wait for postgres to be started.

Comment: @ZeissS thanks so much for your suggestion, I can't find any example of this, is it documented?

Comment: I found the documentation https://github.com/reinoudk/step-service-check

Comment: Implementing a  `service-check` step did not solve my problem with connecting to the docker posgres serveice.

Comment: mh, no-route-to-host seems a bit more weird. Are you running on the classic stack by any chance? I would go and contact the support, they might be able to help you better.

Comment: @ZeissS I am also facing the exact issue did you face any issues regarding this

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava I can only recommend you joining their slack channel or contacting support.

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava@Zeiss I spent at least 16 hours working on this and never solved it. Contacted support, emailed a link to this question, and no response. Final resolution was switched to a paid account at Travis-CI.